# Why does the skins hanger make me exit the game?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Every time I tap the skins hanger, it takes me to my home screen and makes me exit the game. What's happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think this is a question about MCPE

Answer (score -1):

Try getting MCPE Master and a get a skin from there and apply it. Afterwards you should be able to press on the skins button.

Comment: This does not provide a solution and looks almost like a promotion.